# Assertion Failed when reading file

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to open a file and copy into the memory (on Visual Studio, C++).

this is part of the hole code:

```
void *ptr;
FILE *file;
int size;


app->file = fopen("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop file.txt", "r");
ptr = malloc(BUFF_SIZE);
size = fread(ptr, 1, BUFF_SIZE, app->file);
```

right after the last line, I get the error:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
```

what am I doing wrong here..?

thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could add some more information ? Like which kind of debug assertion happened ? Why don't you try to check out the Call Stack ?

Comment: Did `fopen()` succeed? There is no check to confirm that it did, potentially passing a `NULL` pointer to `fread()`. Same for `malloc()`.

Comment: o.k the fopen seemed to failed...the file is on the Desktop, whats wrong..?

Comment: @user3378689 The path you wrote isn't to a file on the desktop.

Comment: I tried to change it another folder and the file is still not opening:
"C:\\folder file.txt"

Comment: @user3378689 If you have a file called "file.txt" in the folder "C:\folder", that's not its path. It would be "C:\folder\file.txt".

Comment: im sorry! I didnt noticed the space before the "file.txt".
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should check for successful open:

```
void *ptr;
FILE *file;
int size;

app->file = fopen("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\file.txt", "r");
if (app->file) {
    ptr = malloc(BUFF_SIZE);
    size = fread(ptr, 1, BUFF_SIZE, app->file);
}
```

Note that the full path has a `\` between the directory name and the file name, not a blank.

Comment: Im sorry, its just typo.. it supposed to be app->file = fopen(...)